# Are negative values acceptable for the Variance Ratio Criterion (VRC)?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I'm using a tutorial for the Variance Ratio Criterion (VRC) by Calinski and Harabasz 1974 ([pdf](http://www.guide-market-research.com/L3UXRpWEecff/attachments/024_Variance%20Ratio%20Criterion.pdf)).  In my case this entails the following steps:

- Conduct k-means clustering on my dataset for k=2 to k=21
- From the ANOVA table add the F values of each variable for each execution of the k-means method. This leads to 20 VRC values (All positive)
- Next the guide says to get the "correct" number of segments by in the kase of k=3 using:

  ```
  W(3) = (VRC(k=4)-VRC(k=3)) - (VRC(k=3)-VRC(k=2))
  ```

In my case this leads to some negative values for W(x). Is this acceptable?  If so, should I use absolute values and select the lowest absolute value? Or should I select the W(X) that is most negative?

Comment: Calinski - Harabasz criterion cannot be negative, it is computed from sums of squares, not fom F values. You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: On page 5 of the guide I link to the authors state the following:

"To compute the VRC statistic for each case of number of segments, we simply sum up the F-values from Tables A9.1-A9.5, using a spreadsheet program such as Microsoft Excel. The results are shown in Table A9.6"

Can you maybe take a look at that and explain to me why they do that? Or maybe even tell me they do it wrong and point me to a better guide?

Comment: I see no link here. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Sorry, it was very unclear indeed (only a small 1) I updated my post to show the link more clearly. I will fix the layout later tonight, I'm on my phone now